# GAE detect running place at localhost or appspot

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have GAE Application. It uses Oauth 2.0 protocol.  I use Java library at the moment.
At the moment, I manually switch the redirect URL.

When I'm testing on localhost I use `localhost:8888/oauth2callback` 
And when I deploy app, I set  `example.appspot.com/oauth2callback.`

So how can I detect, if the app is running on the localhost or is deployed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine AppEngine for Java environment programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993199/determine-appengine-for-java-environment-programmatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_environment%3a), you can do the following

You can check the value of the System property `com.google.appengine.runtime.environment` to determine if it is "Production"  or "Development".

Sample code from docs:

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
// The app is running on App Engine...
}
```

and so on.

On the Python side of things, check out the following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_environment) snippet:

- SERVER_SOFTWARE: In the development web server, this value is "Development/X.Y" where "X.Y" is the version of the runtime. When running on App Engine, this value is "Google App Engine/X.Y.Z".

Answer (score 0):

You can use oAuthService methods to detect localhost environment

[OAuth for Java Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/)

> [...]
>   On the local development server, oauth.getCurrentUser() always returns
>   a User object with email set to "example@example.com" and user ID set
>   to 0 regardless of whether or not a valid OAuth request was made.
>   [...]