# Check Google App Engine server parameters

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have learned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843246/gae-detect-running-place-at-localhost-or-appspot) how can I detect if I am running on development or a production server. Is there some way how to get programmatically following:

- protocol used (http / https)
- port used (8080 / 80)
- server domain (xxx.appspot.com on production)

I can special case them for a development / production, but it smells to me - getting those values from a server would seem nicer to me. Is there a way?

I need those values so that I can construct `redirectUri` for OAuth authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the web framework you're using. If you're using webapp2, you can get it from the request attribute

https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes

For java servlet, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: I am not using any framework, just GAE SDK. I am using Scala / Java - webapp2 seems like a Python framework.

Comment: I am using JSP, which also provides me with a `request` object. I am not sure what to do with your current answer, which is not for Java. Will you edit it, or should I post a new one for Java (which is tag of this question)?

Comment: To be honest I didn't see the java tag, I only read the description. This should help if you have the request object http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html