# Can I detect if an Endpoint is running locally or is deployed?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

Is it possible to detect in code if an Endpoint invocation is happening on a local backend or in production (ie deployed to google servers)?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993199/determine-appengine-for-java-environment-programmatically should serve you well -- it's not specific to endpoints, but should work just as well for any app engine app.

Comment: Alex, please post your reply as an answer so I can mark it as correct. Or if it's more appropriate I can delete the question as a duplicate, let me know what you prefer. thx

Comment: done -- it's an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [Determine AppEngine for Java environment programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993199/determine-appengine-for-java-environment-programmatically) should serve you well -- it's not specific to endpoints, but should work just as well for any app engine app, to find out if you're currently running your App Engine app in a local development setup, or deployed on Google's cloud.