# Check if a container is running on Google Cloud platform

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

When my service is running on Google Cloud, I would like to do some things differently than when I test it locally - namely use a different logger. I could pack some special file when building the Docker image when  deploying and check for that, but perhaps there is a simpler way? I have used Google App Engine before and there was a simple API I could call to check this (see [Determine AppEngine for Java environment programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993199/determine-appengine-for-java-environment-programmatically)). Is there something like available for Cloud Run?

*Note: I use Cloud Run and JVM at the moment, i.e. Docker containers, but if the answer is applicable for Kubernetes or other Google Cloud environments, it might help other users in a similar situation.*

Comment: I'd suggest using environment variables or a similar configuration mechanism to explicitly select the logger and other features you want.  This will be clearer and easier to test, and it will reduce the potential surprise when something fails in production but works locally.

Comment: Env vars is the solution but, personally, I don't like to test a different thing than I use in production, event if it's only logging. Env consistency is paramount for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of these variables to check if your service running in Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#services-env-vars

I will suggest you to use `K_SERVICE` - if that has a value, your service running in Cloud Run.